# Got a syntax error while trying to use lambda function

Tags: python, lambda

I was trying to write a lambda and extracting the value from a dictionary, but it come back with syntax error. I could not tell whats when wrong, please help

---

```
 page2 = {'tsrightdominion.blogspot.com': 0.00034787826123863585,
 'democraticunderground.com': 0.00405450384913243,
 'conservativepunk.com': 0.0004385189536822286,
 'anncoulter.org': 0.0009425724015017965,
 'aldaynet.org': 0.0012959749358987345,
 'gevkaffeegal.typepad.com/the_alliance': 0.0033127018380988433,
 'coxandforkum.com': 0.0026879530285120485,
 'wonkette.com': 0.004395058499406301,
 'hughhewitt.com': 0.006703806759727871,
 'blogsforbush.com': 0.012508582138399097,
 'drudgereport.com': 0.01071241551989842}

 name2 =[lambda val: for key,val in page2.items() if key == 'anncoulter.org']
```

---

```
  File "<ipython-input-44-c0422c8a8a14>", line 1
    name2 =[lambda val: for key,val in page2.items() if key == 'anncoulter.org']
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I am using python

Comment: I think you're looking for `[val for key,val in page2.items() if key == 'anncoulter.org']`

Comment: You are possibly mixing lambdas and list conprehensions. To extract the values you do not need any lambdas: just teplace the `lambda val:` with `val`

Comment: What do you expect as the value of `name2`?  Your syntax in that line suggests that you have a list of a single element, that element being a lambda function with one parameter.  a `for` loop is not a legal functional value -- that's why you have a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the correct syntax

```
name2 = [val for key,val in page2.items() if key == 'anncoulter.org']
```

Result `[0.0009425724015017965]`

Comment: Mind you that this isn't a lambda, it's a list comprehension (which does indeed seem to be what OP wants)

Comment: Which, of course, ir pretty much the same as `name2 = page2['anncoulter.org']` (except it's not wrapped in a list)

Comment: Haha you beat me to it while I was answering from mobile.

Comment: lol, i should've thought about it, thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need lambda here. You tried using list comprehension and lambda together which don't go together in this case.

Just go with

```
[val for key, val in your_dict.items() if your_truth_condition]
```

Hurray you got you list of val from dict.

Comment: ah! thats why! Thanks!